# Don't know what's wrong with my javascript To-Do-List

Tags: javascript, local-storage

So I've been following a tutorial to create a to-do-list using javascript. I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my code.

```
function addTask (e) {
  if(formInput.value === "") {
    alert("You havn't written any tasks!");
  } else {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    const textNode = document.createTextNode(formInput.value);
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.className = "secondary-content deleteTask";
    link.innerHTML = `<i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>`;
    link.style.color = "red";
    li.classList.add("collection-item");
    li.appendChild(textNode);
    li.appendChild(link);
    ul.appendChild(li);
    saveToLocalStorage(formInput.value); 
    formInput.value="";
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

The code above gets executed when the user submits the form and as you can see towards the end of the function I call the function "saveToLocalStorage" and I pass in the input of my form as its parameter.
Here is the saveToLocalStorage function:

```
function saveToLocalStorage(userInput){
  let taskList;

  if(localStorage.getItem("tasks") === null) {
    taskList = [];
  } else {
    taskList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks"));
  }
  taskList.push(userInput);

  localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(taskList));
}
```

However, when I submit my value into the form the page refreshes automatically and nothing gets saved to the local storage.
This is the error that I receive in my console:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please open console, do `console.log(localStorage.getItem("tasks"))` and update your post with the output of that too.

Comment: I ended up restarting my computer and now I don't seem to get any error and the code seems to be working fine. I have no idea why this is? But before when It gave me the error, console.log(localStorage.getItem("tasks")) was giving me something like: [```]